# Refraction of light as seen from a glass of water

Tags: optics, water, refraction, glass

When we put a straw in a glass of water the size and bending is more when viewd from side than from up. Is this due to the effect of the glass?

Answer (score 0):

Precisely more light comes through the medium of water to glass to air and hits our eye hence it looks more "bended" when viewed from side
When viewed from up the light comes mostly from water to air and our eye hence refraction is less